# Multiple value assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a, b, n = 0, 1, 500
while a < n:
    print(a)
    a, b = b, a+b
```

and

```
a, b, n = 0, 1, 500
while a < n:
    print(a)
    a = b
    b = a+b
```

Both give different output. 
What is the difference between   `a, b = b, a+b`  and `a = b; b = a+b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a, b, n = 0, 1, 500
while a < n:
    print(a)
    a = b
    b = a+b
```

In above line of code - after print(a), code value in b variable will be assigned to a first and hence the value of a is updated and the updated value of a is being used in b = a+b

Lets say, a =0, b =1 . So after print(a), value of a will be 1 first and b will have 1+1 =2.

Whereas,

```
a, b, n = 0, 1, 500
while a < n:
    print(a)
    a, b = b, a+b
```

In the above code, after print(a), a and b values are simultaneously assigned. In this case, whatever value of a is printed in print(a) will be used in assigning value for a in further step.

Lets say, a = 0 and b = 1 ,
after print(a) which will print 0 first,  value in a will be 1 and value in b will be 0+1 = 1 because b = a+b will use a =0 and not a =1.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is like swapping.

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

Its like doing this

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp + b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

is equivalent to

```
tmp = a
a = b
b = tmp+b
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not comma separated values. You are doing tuple unpacking.

```
a, b, n = 0, 1, 500
```

Is the same as:

```
a, b, n = (0, 1, 500)
```

The reason they are different is the first line assigns `b` to `a` then adds a and b together. It’s essentially the same as:

```
a = b
b = a+b
```